# Is there a more beautiful way to catch errors on a block of JSON Arrays?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, default-value, short-circuiting

I have a bunch of data in a JSON that I need to parse, but some of them does not exist.

Hence, I currently, have the following `try/catch(e)` but is there a more elegant way to do so?

```
for (var u = 0; u < 100; u++) {
      try {
        var reactions = JSON.parse(dataParsed.data[u].reactions.summary.total_count)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        var reactions = 0
      }
      try {
        var comments = JSON.parse(dataParsed.data[u].comments.summary.total_count)
      } catch (err) {
        var comments = 0
      }
      try {
        var shares = JSON.parse(dataParsed.data[u].shares.count);
      } catch (err) {
        var shares = 0
      }

      postArray.push({
        "id": dataParsed.data[u].id,
        "message": dataParsed.data[u].message,
        "createdTime": dataParsed.data[u].created_time,
        "fullPicture": dataParsed.data[u].full_picture,
        "reactions": reactions,
        "comments": comments,
        "shares": shares
      })
}
```

Comment: is `dataParsed` already parsed (like the name suggests), or not? If it is, why do `JSON.parse` again? If it is not, shouldn't you parse only the first part -- the JSON string at the top level (i.e. `JSON.parse(dataParsed).data[u].comments.summary.total_count`)?

Comment: Show us what `dataParsed` looks like for better answers. In particular, if it is already an object, or still a String.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&&` ([**short circuiting**](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb) ) and `||` ([**default vlaue**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description))

```
var reactions = dataParsed && dataParsed.data[u] &&  dataParsed.data[u].reactions && dataParsed.data[u].reactions.summary && dataParsed.data[u].reactions.summary.total_count || 0
```

There's a proposal for [**optional chaining**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) and [**Nullish Coalescing**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing)

```
var reactions = dataParsed?.data[u]?.reactions?.summary?.total_count ?? 0
```

Comment: Given that the OP was `var reactions = JSON.parse(...)` it might be better if the default value is valid JSON, otherwise you're just changing one error for another. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a function:

```
function safeParse(propStr) {
  let r = 0;
  try {
    r = propStr.split(/\.|\[|\]/g).reduce((a, c) => a[c], {});
  } catch(e) {}
  return r;
}

var reactions = safeParse("dataParsed.data[u].reactions.summary.total_count");
var comments = safeParse("dataParsed.data[u].comments.summary.total_count");
var shares = safeParse("dataParsed.data[u].shares.count");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `value|0` to catch the value via binary operation. If `value` exists, then it will return `value` if not, then it will return `0`

Comment: Unless *value* happens to be a useful falsey value, like `null` or `false`. ;-)

Comment: oh yeah that's a good point. In that case, such a short solution probably isn't possible :/